# Migrating Data from a Server Table to another Server Table

Tags: sql-server

I have around 20 databases that are all existing on two different servers. One server contains all the data but the other one has the same tables but are empty. How can I take all the data existing in the first server and push it to the same tables in the second server?
I thought of manually exporting the tables one by one but that will take so much time so maybe there is an easy way to do so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Backup / Restore an option?  Is this a one-time thing or will you need to repeat this process?

Comment: it's a one time thing, my backups are generated in two files (mdf and ldf) so I am not avle to restore them

Comment: Those are your data (mdf) and transaction log (ldf) files, not backups.  Typically full backups have a .bak extension.  For a one-time thing just run full (copy-only) backups and restore them to the target server.

Comment: I would consider export data tier seeing as your tables are empty. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/export-a-data-tier-application?view=sql-server-ver15. Right click the database and select export data tier. then import data tier to put in on the other server. Or look into SSIS, but I never really understood it or put much time into learning it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45102203/copying-data-from-one-database-to-another-using-ssis

Comment: A one-time backup and restore would seem to be the obvious and probably only sensible option, not to mention fastest.

Answer (score 0):

I would try [Import\Export wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/import-and-export-data-with-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15)